# Magento 1.9.x Custom attribute list in catalog/product list page

Tags: magento-1.9, custom, product-list, insertlisting

I'm definitely not a programmer, I struggle to program a television recording.

However I have to see a list of attributes in the short description of the magento 1.9 product list.

I created a custom attribute that has multiple variables that can be selected simultaneously.

`Example:`
Attribute title: Ingredients
values ​​attrivuto, salt, oil, pepper, etc. etc.

This attribute is enabled to be visible in the front end.

After some research and various copy / paste and many attempts I came to this result.

I purposely used two different "get" that provide two different results

In the file list.html, inside the div class = "desc std" I entered the following code:

FIRST CUSTOMIZED example

```
<br> <? php echo $ _product-> getResource () -> getAttribute ('MIEI_ATTRIBUTI_1') -> getStoreLabel ()?>: <? php echo $ _product-> getAttributeText ('MIEI_ATTRIBUTI_1')?>
```

If it were just "salt" magento correctly returns "salt"
, but in this case there are more chosen variables and magento returns the word "Array" after the title
instead of writing "salt, pepper, oil etc etc"

SECOND CUSTOMIZED ATTRIBUTION

```
<br> <? php echo $ _product-> getResource () -> getAttribute ('MIEI_ATTRIBUTI_2') -> getStoreLabel ()?>: <? php echo $ _product-> getData ('MIEI_ATTRIBUTI_2')?>
```

In this case magento returns the "id" 1,2,3, etc., etc. instead of "salt, pepper, oil, etc."

sorry English I used google translator

How can I solve it?
Can you help me?
Thank you

Comment: Soluzione:<br><?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('ingredienti_pizza')->getStoreLabel() ?>: <?php $attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('ingredienti_pizza');
if ($attribute){
    echo $attribute_value = $attribute ->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
}?>
                    <br><?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('allergeni')->getStoreLabel() ?>: <?php $attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('allergeni');
if ($attribute){
    echo $attribute_value = $attribute ->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
}?>

Comment: Do you want to display all the options which are selected in the backend?